# convert a list of strings to vector types

Tags: r

Is there a way to convert list of strings in a way we write a vectors.

Example

```
out
"input$A" "input$B" "input$C" "input$D" "input$E"
```

Expected output

```
out
input$A,input$B,input$C,input$D,input$E
```

Edited Expected output that i can use

```
data.frame(out)
data.frame(input$A,input$B,input$C,input$D,input$E)
```

Comment: I feel like there is more to this question - are you able to give background on what it is you are trying to do with this code? Is your expected output a character vector, or R code which you are trying to execute?

Comment: What is the end purpose?

Comment: Sure. I have a shiny application. Where I need to create a dummy dataframe based on number of characters I have. So in this case, I can use ````data.frame(input$A,input$B,input$C,input$D,input$E)````

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `out <- c("input$A", "input$B", "input$C", "input$D", "input$E")`; `paste0(out, collapse = ",")`

Comment: Kind off. But we have double quotes at the end?

Answer (score 0):

As desired option the solution in the reply what work from the OP is:

```
library(gsubfn)
out <- c("input$A", "input$B", "input$C", "input$D", "input$E")
pasteout <- as.name(as.character(as.factor(paste0(out, collapse=","))))
cat(gsub("`","",pasteout),sep = ",", "\n")
```

Out after `cat` and `gsub`:

```
input$A,input$B,input$C,input$D,input$E,
```

---

My solution provided does not fit for the OP:

```
 list <- c("A","B","C","D")
my_function <- function(x){
  paste0("input$",x)
}
df <- t(data.frame(lapply(list,my_function)))

print(df)
           [,1]     
X.input.A. "input$A"
X.input.B. "input$B"
X.input.C. "input$C"
X.input.D. "input$D"
```

---

Comment: Not exactlty. But I tried something i like this ````as.name(as.character(as.factor(paste(out, collapse=","))))
`input$A,input$B,input$C,input$D,input$E````

Comment: I got this output ````  `input$A,input$B,input$C,input$D,input$E`  ````. But can we remove ` ` at both the ends?

Comment: `install.packages("gsubfn")
library(gsubfn)
out <- c("input$A", "input$B", "input$C", "input$D", "input$E")
pasteout <- as.name(as.character(as.factor(paste0(out, collapse=","))))
cat(gsub("`", "",pasteout))`
Will do that

Comment: cat(gsub("`", "",pasteout))

Comment: Thanks. But it is removing the comma in between as well. But I need comma as well

Comment: Looks like the , is maintained
cat(gsub("`","",pasteout),sep = ",", "\n")